# ¿Cómo ordenar observaciones de una matriz para análisis de cluster de texto en R? (ver comentarios)

Tags: r, matrices, cluster, nlp, text-mining

Nota: Si es necesario incluir todo el código, háganmelo saber por favor, ya que me cuesta mucho pensar en cómo hacer un ejemplo reproducible.

Básicamente tengo una matriz como esta pero que contiene un total de 1037 renglones:

```
head(dtc, 20)
             Docs
Terms         1 2 3
  911         5 0 0
  abandonadas 1 0 0
  abierto     1 0 0
  abrir       1 0 0
  abuelos     1 0 0
  acaba       1 0 0
  acabar      1 0 0
  acabe       2 0 0
  acceso      1 0 0
  accesos     1 0 0
  accidentes  1 0 0
  accion      3 0 0
  acciones    1 0 0
  acesinatos  1 0 0
  acorde      1 0 0
  actividades 5 0 0
  actualidad  1 0 0
  actualmente 1 0 0
  actuar      1 0 0
  acudan      1 0 0
```

Lo que deseo es obtener quitar las columnas Docs 2 y 3 y ordenar Docs 1 de mayor a menor con el fin de hacer un análisis de clusters. Sin embargo, puede verse la estructura poco convencional de esta matriz:

```
> str(dtc)
 num [1:1037, 1:3] 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ Terms: chr [1:1037] "911" "abandonadas" "abierto" "abrir" ...
  ..$ Docs : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
```

Lo que no me permite ingresar a los índices. Por ejemplo:

```
dtc[order(dtc$Terms, decreasing=T),]
Error in dtc$Terms : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

dtc[order(dtc["Terms",], decreasing=T),]
Error in dtc["Terms", ] : subíndice fuera de  los límites
```

Por otra parte, intenté lo siguiente:

```
dtc <- as.data.frame(dtc) %>%
rename_at(1, function(x) "n") %>% ##Se renombra ya que para usar arrange no se permiten números
select(-3,-4) %>%
arrange(desc(n)) %>%
as.matrix()
```

Pero sólo obtengo

```
> head(dtc)
       n 2
[1,] 175 0
[2,] 146 0
[3,]  55 0
[4,]  48 0
[5,]  33 0
[6,]  31 0
```

Es decir, que los nombres de renglones se perdieron.

Fundamentalmente, me interesa llegar a algo como esto:

```
> dtc <- as.matrix(inspect(dtmcons))
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 1037, documents: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1040/2071
Sparsity           : 67%
Maximal term length: 18
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
              Docs
Terms            1 2 3
  apoyo         31 0 0
  delincuencia  48 0 0
  gobierno      23 0 0
  inseguridad  175 0 0
  municipio     33 0 0
  policia      146 0 0
  robos         25 0 0
  rondines      25 0 0
  valores       25 0 0
  vigilancia    55 0 0
```

Pero con más términos (20, 30, por ejemplo) para después utilizar la función `dist` y las relacionadas con análisis de cluster. 
Agradezco de antemano cualquier comentario y orientación.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que `dplyr` se lleva mal con los `row.names` que heredas de la matriz y y las matrices se llevan mal con los nombres en una columna, ya que obligan a coercionar a carácter a los numéricos. La solución es hacer una conversión a columna explícita cuando está en data.frame y después regresar a `row.names`  antes de pasarlo a matriz.

```
library(tidyverse)   # Incluye library(tibble), para pasar de row.names a columna y viceversa. 

dtc %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% #Esto te faltaba.
  rename(n = V1) %>% 
  select (rowname, n) %>% 
  column_to_rownames() %>% #Los heredará la matriz que viene después
  as.matrix() -> dtc
```

Hice un test con datos similares a los tuyos y funcionó. Si este código te falla pon un `dput(head(dtc))` en tu pregunta para rastrear el problema en tus daos.

Saludos.

> PD: https://www.tidytextmining.com/dtm.html te puede interesar. Expone funciones de `tidytext`  para hacer el tipo de trabajo que te interesa, pasar de formato `tidy` a matrices de palabras.
>
> PD2: por lo que se vé estás haciendo procesamiento de lenguaje natural. La librería `udpipe` es muy interesante para eso, tiene modelo de lenguaje en español y funciona bastante bien para crear lemmas, anotar funciones gramatical de cada palabra, etc.

Comment: Funcionó de maravilla. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a obtener los nombres usando `row.names` de esa matriz?

Es cierto que originalmente se usa para `data.frames`, pero con las matrices no hay problema en obtenerlos, sean indices o nombres.